# Is there a way to filter mail based on timestamp rather than just date in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

In thunderbird, we can filter mail based on a number of constraints including date. But, I don't see a way to use timestamp to filter rather than date alone.

Is there no way for it? Sounds strange imo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you can filter *incoming* mail on a timestamp, in a roundabout way.

1. Go to "Edit / Find... / Search messages..." or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>.
2. Click on the `Subject` dropdown field and click "Customise...".
3. In the New Message Header field, type `Date` (or `Delivery-date`, or
   `Received`, all of these may work)
4. Click `Add`.
5. In the input field, type an exact date string like `05 Feb 2017 21:09`. Leave the middle field at `Contains`.
6. Click `Search`.

Your search will turn up all messages that were received at that time. You can't, unfortunately, search for messages received before or after a certain timestamp. For this, you need to widen the criteria, then sort on "Date received".

Comment: Before I saw your answer, I ended up sorting filtered mails by date, selecting mail there within the timestamp range, and then applying the operation I wanted to do. This idea is better I guess.